# Naming Sheets & Creating Hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am creating a new sheet:

```vb
Dim Naming As String
Dim ProjectNumber As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Naming = CallLaunched.Value & " - " & ProjectLead.Value

ws.Name = Naming
```

This gives me a Sheet called something like: "May-21 - Sam Smith"

I want to hyperlink to that new sheet from another sheet so I use this:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("A" & LastRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=Naming & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=ProjectNumber
```

When I click on the hyperlink I get

> Reference isn't valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheet names with spaces need quotes:

```
SubAddress:= "'" & Naming & "'!A1"
```